# Keyboard Shortcut for Windows Explorer to fit the width of the name column to the longest file name in the folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

I would like to use a keyboard shortcut to fit the Name column to the longest name of the files in the folder so the file names don't get truncated with `...`. In a desktop you can use [`Ctrl` + `+`] to fit the name column with to the length of the longest filename in the folder.

However, it does not work in my Dell Laptop. Any alternative shortcut for when we are in a laptop?

[image: Windows Explorer Example of filenames ending in ...]

Comment: The problem isn't the laptop.. it is that you need to use the "+" on a numeric keypad to use this shortcut (which most laptop keyboards don't have).. also.. it's just one "+" and not "++".  Sorry I don't have an answer for you.  This response is wired into the list view control as long as it isn't owner drawn.  I too would like to know if there is *another way*.. hopefully someone knows (but I doubt it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> auto sizes all columns.

Tab to the column header, arrow key to name, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.

Or double click the border between columns.

Comment: it will only resize to the with of the longest filename currently visible though.